# How to get value of element with XDocument and Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to collect the `RequestID` element with the namespace, but I do not know how.

```
this.XmlString =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" 
encoding=\"utf-8\"?><MethodNameRq xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" 
xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><RequestID 
xmlns=\"http://Mynamespace\">573-348976-428697-346</RequestID ></MethodNameRq>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(this.XmlString);

this.RequestId = (string)doc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name 
                 == "RequestID ").FirstOrDefault();
```

This collects an empty string for `RequestID`. It does work if the string has no namespaces included. Does anyone know how I can collect the RequestID element?

Comment: Is the call of `Parse` actually working? The string seems to be no valid xml because of the timestamp in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks @Codor, yes it is valid "on my machine". I copy pasted the full string accidentally. Changed it to reflect the actual situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to specify the namespace of your element

```
XNamespace ns = "http://Mynamespace";

this.RequestId = (string)doc.Descendants(ns + "RequestID").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I did not know that XNamespace could be a string. :)

Comment: it can be because there is an implicit conversion defined from string to XNamespace. You can find more information about XNamespace in this documentation: [Working with XML Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387093.aspx)